# Laravel - Code works in task scheduler but not queue job

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel app, there are comments and users can upvote or downvote comments.

Rather than calculate the score of a comment (sum of upvotes - downvotes) every time there is a new vote, I use Laravel's [Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) which calculates the score of comments every 10 minutes:

```
public function handle()
{
    $comments = Comment::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))
        ->withCount('upVotes')
        ->withCount('downVotes')
        ->get();

    $comments->each(function ($item) {
        $item->total_upvotes = $item->up_votes_count;
        $item->total_downvotes = $item->down_votes_count;
        $item->total_score = $this->score($item->up_votes_count, $item->down_votes_count);
        $item->fuzzed_score = (int)round($item->total_score + (rand(0,22) / 100 ) * $item->total_score, 0);
        $item->save();
    });
```

Now this works pretty well, but I worry this won't scale very well if my app is getting a massive amount of comments (if I had 1million comments, let's say, then this would likely time out since I'm doing it all in one go). So instead of calculating all the comments at once, I decided to make the task scheduler queue up a job:

```
public function handle()
{
    $comments = Comment::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(3))
        ->withCount('upVotes')
        ->withCount('downVotes')
        ->get();

    $comments->each(function ($item) {
        CalculateCommentScoreJob::dispatch($item);
    });
```

The code in the queue job is the same as what I had in the task scheduler:

```
use Rank;

protected $item; 


public function __construct(Comment $items)
{
    $this->item = $items;
}


public function handle()
{
    $item = $this->item;
    $item->total_upvotes = $item->up_votes_count;
    $item->total_downvotes = $item->down_votes_count;
    $item->total_score = $this->score($item->up_votes_count, $item->down_votes_count);
    $item->fuzzed_score = (int)round($item->total_score + (rand(0,22) / 100 ) * $item->total_score, 0);
    $item->save();
}
```

however, this no longer works and is returning the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'total_upvotes' cannot be null
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try to debug what are $item values ? Is it possible that you get $item->up_votes_count equal to null in some cases ?

Comment: No, it seems that the relationship isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below. You have to use $this->item instead of $item which you are passing in constructor.

```
use Rank;

protected $item; 


public function __construct($item)
{
    $this->item = $item;
}


public function handle()
{
    $item = $this->item;
    $item->total_upvotes = $this->item->up_votes_count;
    $item->total_downvotes = $this->item->down_votes_count;
    $item->total_score = $this->score($this->item->up_votes_count, $this->item->down_votes_count);
    $item->fuzzed_score = (int)round($this->item->total_score + (rand(0,22) / 100 ) * $this->item->total_score, 0);
    $item->save();
}
```

Comment: First check that you are receiving the $item in handel(). I have edited the code try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the relationship wasn't being passed through, I just passed upvotes and downvotes manually to the job, like so:

```
    $comments->each(function ($item) {
        
        $upvotes = $item->up_votes_count;
        $downvotes = $item->down_votes_count;
        CalculateCommentScoreJob::dispatch($item,$upvotes,$downvotes);
```